# Catboost CTR for binary classification

Tags: python, catboost

I was reading through the documentation at https://tech.yandex.com/catboost/doc/dg/concepts/algorithm-main-stages_cat-to-numberic-docpage/ and couldn't find the default settings Catboost uses to encode categorical variables in case of a binary target.

Specifically, I couldn't find what type of encoding method it uses (bucket, counter, ...) and what are the default values of prior.

Also, it wasn't very clear how encodings are calculated for the test set. Since we don't know the value of target, do we just keep them constant?